# iMacro to generate random text or random numbers for twitter

Tags: twitter, imacros

I want to tweet randomly so I won't get a message from twitter saying you already tweeted that.

Here is the code that isn't working with random text. How can I add to this so I can enter random text/numbers to tweet?

code:

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/
WAIT SECONDS=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#tweet-box-home-timeline" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=2
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#tweet-box-home-timeline" CHARS="#twitter "
WAIT SECONDS=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#timeline>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a random text from the set defined by you, try this:

```
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/
WAIT SECONDS=1
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#tweet-box-home-timeline" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=2

' define and add your texts here
SET texts "['randomText1', 'randomText2', 'randomText3']"
SET rndText EVAL("var texts = eval('{{texts}}'); texts[Math.floor(Math.random()*(texts.length))];")
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#tweet-box-home-timeline" CHARS={{rndText}}

WAIT SECONDS=2
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#timeline>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>FORM>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
WAIT SECONDS=4
```